# SpringBoot RestController returns 405 for path 'services/*'

Tags: rest, spring-boot, soap

We recently updated a project to spring boot version '1.5.6.RELEASE' and noticed that several REST-services did not work anymore. We found out that it has to do with the RequestMapping - when a Rest-URL starts with 'services/', the Request always returns a HTTP 405 (Method not allowd). Changing that path a bit, it works again. Our API uses this 'services/...' paths. This only seems to occur when I also use soap services.

**Has anyone a hint to solve this?**

*Here is a simple working example:*
https://github.com/gemdat/rest_demo/tree/master

Comment: which version of Spring Boot did you upgrade from?

Comment: we updated from 1.3.8

Answer (score 3):

We finally found the problem - due to a spring servlet refactoring we had to adjust the 'webservice path' in the application.properties...

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/services/rest
spring.webservices.path=/services/soap
```